# PHP Xdebug outputting stack trace error for no reason

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm running Ubuntu 20.

```text
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2023 18:31:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
 with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
 with Xdebug v3.1.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

and when I debug, I run into issues that say :

```html
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: raw_input_data</p>
<p>Filename: /debug-eval</p>
<p>Line Number: 1</p>
<p>Backtrace:</p>       
    <p style="margin-left:10px">
    File: xdebug://debug-eval<br />
    Line: 1<br />
    Function: _error_handler
    </p>
```

When I run the code normally, there is no issues with `raw_input_data` variable. I have also tried running the code on another computer with the same PHP / Xdebug version and there is no problem with the source code itself.

I have tried reinstalling Xdebug, and it does not make a difference.
I've tried changing the `log_level` to `0` but it does not make a difference also.

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=start
xdebug.log_level = 0
```

Running out of ideas short of trying to reinstall PHP and the IDE.

Comment: "I have also tried running the code on another computer with the same php / xdebug version and there is no problem with the source code itself." Incorrect. It has the same problem, but you're ignoring Notice-level messages and also don't have xdebug configured to raise Notices as exceptions.

Comment: On vscode, I have checked notices, errors, warnings,and everything and xdebug does not break on any notices. I can step through properly until end of code and then it will throw these errors up.

Comment: The issue was VScode had some watch expressions that were undefined during step through. It caused xdebug to throw stack traces on that. I think it's a bug as I have used watch expressions before, and there wasn't any issues. Will continue to investigate